# Visual Studio 2017 C++, can't use typeid() to take information object, missing pointer?;

Tags: c++, typeid

Thats my first post here xD.

Recently, I began to remind myself of knowledge in the field of c ++ after a few years of break. Previously, I worked in C #.

As part of the exercises, I started to write the code which is to generate the class of the car, and then to enter and write data.
But I came across a problem. As part of the exercise I wanted to write the name of the object using the function typeid () and find out what is hash_code.
But I got two mistakes and I can not do what.
How to correctly declare a pointer.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Car {
public:
    string _mark;
    string _model;
    int _year;
    int _course;

    void UploadData()
    {
        cout << "Set values" << endl;
        cin >> _mark;
        cin >> _model;
        cin >> _year;
        cin >> _course;
        cout << "Values uploaded"<<endl;
    }

    void Write()
    {
        cout << typeid(this).name <<" " << typeid(this).hash_code << " " << " mark " << _mark << " model " << _model << " year " << _year << " course " << _course;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Car test1;
    test1.UploadData();
    test1.Write();
}
```

Error Messege:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C3867   'type_info::name': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create
>   a pointer to member
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C3867   'type_info::hash_code': non-standard syntax; use '&' to
>   create a pointer to member

Comment: Sorry, I'll remove my comment, I was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` and `hash_code` are member functions of class `std::typeinfo`, so you need to use parentheses:

```
cout << typeid(this).name() <<" " << typeid(this).hash_code()
     << " " << " mark " << _mark << " model " << _model << " year " << _year
     << " course " << _course;
```

The error message you got is unfortunately misleading. The compiler thought you were attempting to do something entirely different and more advanced.

But note that `typeid(this)` is going to be exactly the same as `typeid(Car*)`.  If you instead wrote `typeid(*this)`, that would be the same as `typeid(Car)`.  The `typeid` operator starts to get more interesting when used on a class with at least one virtual function....

Comment: So we can close that question as a _simple typo_ now?